# How can I use my custom backend JWT with Next-AUth

Tags: jwt, next.js13, next-auth

I want to know how can I use my custom JWT from my backend in next-auth. I already made some adjustments to the options.ts but one of the problems hasn't gone. The problem is that it creates a JWT in next-auth instead if using mine. For example i get a JWT from my server but the JWT saved in cookies `next-auth.session-token` is different to the one received.

This is my options.ts:

```js
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2h54xz6Ndw&t=1721s

import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google"
import AppleProvider from "next-auth/providers/apple"
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import decode from "jwt-decode";

import loginService from "@/services/auth";

export const options: NextAuthOptions = {
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            name: "Credentials",
            credentials: {
                email: {
                    label: "Email",
                    type: "email",
                    placeholder: "Email"
                },
                password: {
                    label: "Password:",
                    type: "password",
                    placeholder: "Password"
                }
            },
            async authorize(credentials) {
                // This is where you need to retrieve user data 
                // to verify with credentials
                // Docs: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers/credentials
                const email = credentials?.email || "";
                const password = credentials?.password || "";
                try {  
                    let user = await loginService.login(email, password);
                    // modify object
                    user = {
                        token: user.access_token
                    }
                    if (user && user.token) {
                        // const decoded:any = decode(user.token);
                        // let isAdminReq = await loginService.verifyAdmin(decoded.user_id);
                        
                        // if (isAdminReq.valid === true) {
                        //     return user;
                        // }
                        // else return "unauthorized";
                        return user;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    return null;
                } 
            }
        })
    ],
    session: {
        strategy: "jwt",
    },
    callbacks: {
        async jwt({ token, user }) {
            if (user) {
                if (user.token) {
                    token.token = user.token;
                }
            }
            return token;
        },

        async session({ session, token }) {
            session.user = token as any;
            return session;
        },
    },
    pages: {
        signIn: `${process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL}/login` 
    }
};
```

I don0t know what the problem is, but I want to use my own JWT and get rid of another error caused by the NEXTAUTH_SECRET. I want the `next-auth.session-token` to be my backend access token not the one generated by next-auth.